# How to change the direction to Right to Left bars in a bar type chart?

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I'm working with Visual Studio 2015, c# WinForms.

How to set bars of a chart(Bar type) right to left instead of left to right?

Comment: What are you using to draw the chart?

Comment: WinForms toolkit, whatever why is this important?

Comment: There are Chart controls in Winforms, WPF and ASP. They are very similar, however we still need to know which one you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is rather simple. In fact the only issue is to understand that for `Bar` charts the axes are switched, that is the Y-Axis is horizontal, so we want to modify `AxisY`.

All you need to do is **reverse** it:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.IsReversed = true;
```

Before and after:

[image][image]